# MustHaveHappened not being called when using IoC

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, structuremap, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to test that a service call is made.
I have an `IAuthenticationService` that makes an `UpdateUserProfile` call. The `IAuthenticationService` is in the IoC (`StructureMap` in my case).
`MustHaveHappened` is returning `0` calls, but I know it happened from debugging.

```
[TestMethod]
public void It_should_call_the_UpdateUserProfile()
{
    // initialize in the base class, here for brevity
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(registry =>
    {
        registry.For<IAuthenticationService>().Use(A.Fake<IAuthenticationService>());
    });
    UserProfile profileSend = new UserProfile
    {
        UserName = this.HttpContextBaseFake.User.Identity.Name,
        CultureSelection = expectedCultureInfoString
    };

    Utils.UpdateProfile(profileSend);
    IAuthenticationService service = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAuthenticationService>();
    UserProfile profileExpect = new UserProfile
    {
        UserName = this.HttpContextBaseFake.User.Identity.Name,
        CultureSelection = expectedCultureInfoString
    };

    // this is returning 0 calls
    // I've also tried sending in the profileExpect instead of A.Dummy<UserProfile>
    // it would be nice to test for the name and string was sent
    A.CallTo(() => service.UpdateUserProfile(A.Dummy<UserProfile>())).MustHaveHappened();
}

// using static class for a reason, the code in my project has more in it
public static class Utils
{
    public static void UpdateProfile(UserProfile profile)
    {
        // user profile is more easily available, use that for the unique identifier
        IAuthenticationService service = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAuthenticationService>();
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile
        {
            UserName = userProfileName,
            CultureSelection = cultureInfoString
        };

        service.UpdateUserProfile(userProfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess you have an equality issue somewhere - that is usually the case with mock expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use A.Ignored instead of A.Dummy() in the A.CallTo(.

So it becomes:

```
A.CallTo(() => service.UpdateUserProfile(A<UserProfile>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```